# Se una coppia ha un negozio di regali, come si dice?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Se una coppia, di cognome "Benigni", ha un negozio di regali, come si direbbe correttamente nell'insegna:

"Benigni regali", "Regali Benigni", oppure è corretto usare entrambi?

Grazie mille della delucidazione.

Comment: Entrambe le forme vanno bene. Certo, "Regali Benigni" secondo me suona meglio e produce anche un bel doppio senso che potrebbe persino avere un valore in termini di marketing :-)

Comment: @randomatlabuser Se la metti come risposta la posso votare. Grazie, userò Regali Benigni che in effetti è più simpatico.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entrambe le forme vanno bene. Certo, "Regali Benigni" secondo me suona meglio e produce anche un bel doppio senso che potrebbe persino avere un valore in termini di marketing :-)

Comment: Puoi citare una fonte autorevole? Che io sappia la forma "Tipo negozio + nome" e tipicamente italiana mentre "nome + Tipo negozio" è inglese ([fonte non troppo autorevole](http://pignuoli.blogspot.it/2014/05/caffe-qualcosa-o-qualcosa-caffe.html)). Ad esempio si dice *Caffè la dea bendata* e **non** *La dea bendata caffè*. Credo che questo valga non solo per *caffè* ma per qualunque tipo di "negozio"/locale. Dunque *Regali Benigni* dovrebbe essere *l'unica* forma corretta.

Comment: Che io sappia il nome delle insegne è protetto dal diritto d'autore, quindi fondamentalmente ti puoi inventare quello che ti pare, con relativamente poche eccezioni esplicitamente previste dal codice civile (art. 2188 e seguenti). Dal punto di vista linguistico non mi risultano regole perché un'insegna per sua natura associa parole più o meno in libertà.

Comment: Beh, questo mi pare *ovvio*. Io intendevo l'usanza/maniera tradizionale, non una regola grammaticale assoluta. La situazione particolare in questione è molto ambigua perchè le due possibilità sono molto molto simili. Se FF11 ha posto questa domanda vuol dire che gli interessa effettivamente conoscere qual è il modo più tradizionale in Italia. La mia richiesta è: puoi fornire fonti che mostrino che sono entrambe usate con la stessa frequenza in Italia?

Comment: @Bakuriu, no, ho risposto sulla base di quello che mi sembrava fosse buon senso. Se per esempio è vero che normalmente per i bar valga lo schema "bar + nome", per i negozi di giocattoli normalmente vale invece lo schema "nome + giocattoli" (pensa a "Rocco Giocattoli") ma puoi dare un'occhiata [qui](http://roma.paginegialle.it/lazio/roma/giocattoli.html) per farti un'idea. Brevemente e un po' brutalmente: secondo me in questo campo valgono solo le regole del marketing, non credo esistano usanze linguistiche consolidate/tradizionali.

Comment: Fondamentalmente mi interessava saperlo per non fare brutta figura e poi dover rifare tutto il lavoro :-)); poi, si sa, le "regole linguistiche" e "voci del dizionario" vengono cambiati spesso in base alle esigenze ed al tempo in cui ci si trova. Se si sfoglia un dizionario o un libro scolastico degli anni 60 c'è da stupirsi.